# Why doesn’t acc0 need to be cleared in p256OrdMul?

Tags: montgomery-multiplication

`p256OrdMul` method in `crypto/internal/nistec/p256_asm_amd64.s`,

```
// func p256OrdMul(res, in1, in2 *p256OrdElement)
TEXT ·p256OrdMul(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVQ res+0(FP), res_ptr
    MOVQ in1+8(FP), x_ptr
    MOVQ in2+16(FP), y_ptr
    // x * y[0]
    MOVQ (8*0)(y_ptr), t0

    MOVQ (8*0)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    MOVQ AX, acc0
    MOVQ DX, acc1

    MOVQ (8*1)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ AX, acc1
    ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, acc2

    MOVQ (8*2)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ AX, acc2
    ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, acc3

    MOVQ (8*3)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ AX, acc3
    ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, acc4
    XORQ acc5, acc5
    // First reduction step
    MOVQ acc0, AX
    MULQ p256ordK0<>(SB)
    MOVQ AX, t0

    MOVQ p256ord<>+0x00(SB), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ AX, acc0
    ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ p256ord<>+0x08(SB), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc1
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc1
ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ p256ord<>+0x10(SB), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc2
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc2
ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ p256ord<>+0x18(SB), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc3
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc3
ADCQ DX, acc4
ADCQ $0, acc5
    // x * y[1]
    MOVQ (8*1)(y_ptr), t0

    MOVQ (8*0)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ AX, acc1
    ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ (8*1)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc2
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc2
ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ (8*2)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc3
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc3
ADCQ $0, DX
    MOVQ DX, t1

    MOVQ (8*3)(x_ptr), AX
    MULQ t0
    ADDQ t1, acc4
    ADCQ $0, DX
ADDQ AX, acc4
ADCQ DX, acc5
ADCQ $0, acc0
    // Second reduction step
```

This is a **Word-by-Word Montgomery Multiplication (WW-MM)**, we can see that the method reused **acc0** in step x * y[1] but not cleared, the result is still correct.

According my understanding, we should clear **acc0** before we reuse it, what's the logic/formula behind?

Comment: Huh? Why? MOV will overwrite anything in the target afaik. Possibly better asked at a programming Q/A site, but to me this is a strange question.

Comment: After first reduction step, the value in **acc0** can be discarded, and before it's reused in x * y[1] step (ADCQ $0, acc0), We do not find code to set the value to zero, for example XORQ acc0, acc0.